# Is it possible to have InkCanvas surface in shape of a circle/ellipse?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm fairly new to WPF and I'm struggling with something that I believe should not be causing me so much of a headache. All the content I dug out on the topic so far goes on around drawing circles/ellipses on Canvas/InkCanvas surface. However, my question is:

Is it possible to have the InkCanvas area in a shape of a circle/ellipse? If yes, I would really appreciate additional details on the subject.

Thanks!

InkCanvas appears round but active area remains rectangular:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    ...
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF909090" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="180">
            <Grid Width="Auto" Height="325" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            ...
                <InkCanvas x:Name="InkCanvas" Background="{x:Null}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                    ...
                </InkCanvas>
                ...
            </Grid>
        ...
        </Border>
    ...
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could try to place the canvas inside a border then set the border's corner radius property.

```
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="100">
        <InkCanvas Background="{x:Null}"/>
    </Border>
```

Comment: I tried this already and it indeed solves my problem in UI - i.e. canvas appears round. 

However the functionality I'm looking for is still missing as canvas' active surface remains rectangular and still takes up whole space of the grid within which the border is placed. I added code in my post if it helps you.